# Get reset value of field in vr_ad (specman) or simply reset the field

Tags: uvm, specman, e

I'm running a sequence where I need to temporarily write to a certain field in a register, and after a while I wish to reset it back to its reset value. I don't want to reset the entire register using the `reset()` function, I wish only to reset the field. I couldn't find an easy way to access the reset value of the field itself, even though it's defined per field in the `reg_fld` macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `vr_ad_reg::static_info::fields_info` via `vr_ad_reg::get_fields_info()` (provided the static_info exists). This is a list with an item for each field that contains information about the field. Have a look in the data browser, this should help you.

Comment: The `vr_ad_reg::static_info::fields_info` does contain some info, but the reset value for some reason, is not there..

Comment: There is something that is called `vr_ad_reg::static_info::fld_reset_val_list`, but it's empty.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't have a working Specman setup at hand. But the field info gives you the size ``fld_size`` and LSB position ``fld_fidx`` of the field. Using this you can extract the reset value from the reset value of the register, which is ``vr_ad_reg_static_info::reset_value``.